# Boost unit test in separate cpp files

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, boost-test

I want to separate my Boost unit tests into separate .cpp files (e.g. Test1.cpp, Test2.cpp, Test3.cpp ... etc) So that I do not have 1000 tests in a single cpp file. So far I have been getting all kinds of errors when I try to build.

Test1.cpp

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MasterTestSuite
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(myTestCase)
{
  BOOST_CHECK(1 == 1);  
}
```

Test2.cpp

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MasterTestSuite2
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(myTestCase2)
{
  BOOST_CHECK(2 == 2);  
}
```

Comment: "So far I have been getting all kinds of errors when I try to build." - can you give us an example? (Please edit it into the question)

Comment: [This section](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/usage_variants.html) indicates that `BOOST_TEST_MODULE` should be defined only once for a single binary, and 
[this section](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/adv_scenarios/single_header_customizations/multiple_translation_units.html) of the documentation indicates how to use the header-only approach with multiple translation units.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`boost-test` generates it's own `main` function when you define `BOOST_TEST_MODULE`, see: [BOOST_TEST_MODULE](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/link_references/link_boost_test_module_macro.html). Some of your errors are likely to be because of this.

I put `BOOST_TEST_MODULE` in a separate file, e.g.:

test_main.cpp

```
#ifndef _MSC_VER
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#endif
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE Main
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
```

And then use [test suites](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/test_tree/test_suite.html#ref_BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE) to separate unit tests into separate .cpp files, with a `test suite` in each unit test file e.g.:

Test1.cpp

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(MyTests)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(myTestCase)
{
  BOOST_CHECK(1 == 1);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Test2.cpp

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(MyTests2)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(myTestCase2)
{
  BOOST_CHECK(2 == 2);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

You can find an example of this approach in the tests directory [here](https://github.com/kenba/via-httplib).