# Boost Test usage variants

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, boost

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise 15.9.12 and Visual C++ 2017 00369-90013-89248-AA631 and Boost version 1.71.0.

I have a unit test project, and everything goes find when I had only one file (`AstroTimeTest.cpp`). But, when I have added another file (`CoordinateSystemsTest.cpp`) I get some LINKER errors. To create the second file I have copied some code from the first file.

**AstroTimeTest.cpp** contents:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE astroTimeTests
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#include "../../AstroTime/AstroTime.h"

struct TestFixture
{
    AstroTime time_instance;

    TestFixture()
        : time_instance()
    {}

    ~TestFixture() = default;
};

bool operator ==(astTime const &left, astTime const &right)
{
    return(
        left.secs == right.secs
        && left.min == right.min
        && left.hour == right.hour);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const astTime& dt)
{
    os << dt.hour << "h " << dt.min << "m " << dt.secs << "s" << std::endl;

    return os;
}

bool operator ==(dateTime const &left, dateTime const &right)
{
    return(
        left.t.secs == right.t.secs
        && left.t.min == right.t.min
        && left.t.hour == right.t.hour
        && left.day == right.day
        && left.mon == right.mon
        && left.year == right.year
        && left.daylightSaving == right.daylightSaving
        && left.timeZone == right.timeZone);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const dateTime& dt)
{
    os << dt.t.hour << " " << dt.t.min << " " << dt.t.secs << ", "
        << dt.day << " " << dt.mon << " " << dt.year << std::endl;

    return os;
}

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_SUITE(TestAstroTime, TestFixture)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(ToDecimalHour_1)
{
    double decHour = 18.524167;
    astTime t = {18, 31, 27.0 };

    BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL(decHour, time_instance.ToDecimalHour(t));
}

// *** Removed for brevety **/

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

**CoordinateSystemsTest.cpp** contents:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE coordinateSystemsTests
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#include "../../AstroTime/CoordinateSystems.h"


struct TestFixture
{
    CoordinateSystems coord_instance;

    TestFixture()
        : coord_instance()
    {}

    ~TestFixture() = default;
};

bool operator ==(angle const &left, angle const &right)
{
    return(
        left.secs == right.secs
        && left.min == right.min
        && left.degree == right.degree);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const angle& dt)
{
    os << dt.degree << "º " << dt.min << "' " << dt.secs << "\"" << std::endl;

    return os;
}


BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_SUITE(TestCoordinateSystems, TestFixture)



BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(ToDecimalDegrees_1)
{
    double decDegrees = 182.524167;
    angle degrees = { 182, 31, 27.0 };

    BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL(decDegrees, coord_instance.ToDecimalDegrees(degrees));
}




BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

One of the errors I get is:

> CoordinateSystemsTest.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall
>   boost::unit_test::ut_detail::auto_test_unit_registrar::auto_test_unit_registrar(class
>   boost::unit_test::test_unit_generator const &,class
>   boost::unit_test::decorator::collector_t &)"
>   (??0auto_test_unit_registrar@ut_detail@unit_test@boost@@QAE@ABVtest_unit_generator@23@AAVcollector_t@decorator@23@@Z)
>   already defined in AstroTimeTest.obj

If I remove all the code in `CoordinateSystemsTest.cpp`, I still get the same LINKER error.

But If I remove also this line:

```
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
```

Leaving the file almost empty, I don't get any error.

The error is due to [Boost Test Usage Variants](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/usage_variants.html), because I'm using the *"Single-header usage variant"*. But I don't understand what variant do I have to use.

How can I use more than one CPP file with Boost Test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per **[Header-only with multiple translation units](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/adv_scenarios/single_header_customizations/multiple_translation_units.html)**:

> It is possible to use the header-only variant of the *Unit Test Framework* even if the test module has multiple translation units:
>
> - one translation unit should define `BOOST_TEST_MODULE` and include `<boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>`
> - all the other translation units should include `<boost/test/unit_test.hpp>`

I would recommend having a dedicated TU solely containing

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE header-only multiunit test
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
```

(plus global fixtures, etc.) and all your actual tests in other TUs.

Comment: I have found how to implement what you have suggested in your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57177380/68571

Answer (score 0):

Could you try including the files in the respective .h files? Please also make sure that your header files have #pragma once to remove multiple inclusions.

From my experience adding headers with class definitions in c++ files cause this linker issue

Comment: Thanks. The error is related to this: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/usage_variants.html But I don't understand what are variants and what variant do I have to use here.

Comment: In that case, the answer from @ecatmur seems more relevant.